# getting strange errors when importing external data to excel from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

In Excel I using a Data Table that connects via a data connection string to an sql server procedure.  The procedure accepts some parameters querys and then returns the data to the excel data table.  This has worked well for quite a while.

Now the users have started to randomly get the following error message.

[image]

This is happening randomly as the user try's it again and it works.

Nothing else is on the spreadsheet and the returned information is well within any row count limitation that excel may have.

Comment: Check out the answers from this question. They could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025679/microsoft-excel-cant-insert-new-cells

Comment: There is a video on youtube aswell :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Egs-HOzNusk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to isolate the cause of the error.  If you have something on your clipboard and then refresh your table it causes a conflict when the records are returned.  After clearing my clipboard and refreshing it worked fine.  This most be a flaw in the version of Excel I'm using - 2016.